# Pick version of Java dependency

Tags: java, gradle

In our project we use a library that has dependencies, eg:

```
expo-file-system
     +--- commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10
     +--- commons-io:commons-io:1.4
```

As part of security fix, we suppose to use later version of the dependencies, say. commons-codec:commons-codec:1.14. Without upgrading expo-file-system, is there a way to tell gradle/maven that we want to use a specific version of commons-codec:commons-codec?

Comment: Declare the transient dependency, manually?

Comment: Try using dependency constraints. Check out https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_constraints.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dependencies {
implementation 'commons-codec:commons-codec'
constraints {
    implementation('commons-codec:commons-codec:1.14') {
        because 'security fix'
    }
}
```